# Displaying validation errors with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some trouble rendering validation messages using "remote => true"

I have a partially rendered form for saving an address

```
<%= render :partial => "registrations/address", :locals => {:address => @user.customer_addresses.build, :is_new => true, :checked => false} %>
```

In this form, the user clicks this button to create a new address

```
<%= link_to "Save Address", "javascript://", :remote => true, :data => "new", "data-target" => create_user_address_url, "data-method" => "Post" %>
```

I have the 'create_address' function set up in the controller (which returns the validation errors), as well as a create_address.js.erb file. However, it doesnt seem like the browser is executing anything in the js file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see the code of `js.erb` file
But I assume you have [escape javascript issue](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/when-to-use-escape-javascript-in-an-sjr-template.html).
Just use `j` in your render partial method. E.g.

```
<%= j render('partial_name') %>
```

Comment: My js file is just a console.log, which doesnt execute when i press the link

Comment: It would be great to see the name of this partial and controller.
Do you always render `create.js.erb` ore there could be error.js.erb.
Also if there is some other logic which could be not parsed the behaviour will be the same. Also would be great to see logs output about the controller and what partial is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgot to reload the partial which show the error message. After using remote => true you need to reload the partial so that the changes will reflect on that partial.